# How do you write and retrieve TFRecord features that are lists?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a CNN model that takes N classification labels per training example and I am trying to create TFRecords from my data set that have a label feature that is a list of int64s.

On the shard creation side I am using something like the following. I have put the label data explicitly in the code but obviously it would be different for each sample:

```
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
  ... # other stuff  
  'label': tf.train.Feature(
                  int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[1, 2, 3, 4])}))
writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

On the reading side, I am doing something like the following. I assume a fixed number of labels (4):

```
features = tf.parse_single_example(
      serialized_example,
      # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
      features={
        ... # other stuff
        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature(
            [4], dtype=tf.int64, default_value=-1)}
      )
label = features['label']
```

When I try this Tensorflow reports:

```
ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 1 elements to shape [4] (4 elements)
```

Clearly, I'm not understanding something fairly fundamental

Comment: Comment below clarifies a bug in the code. for a list of values, the default_value argument must conform to the shape. So, instead of default_value=-1, the above code should be default_value=[-1]*4 as mentioned below. I am leaving the post with the bug.

Comment: I have followed your example by inputting the list of of int64s
but I got the following error,

`TypeError: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] has type <type 'list'>, but expected one of: (<type 'int'>, <type 'long'>)`

I am wondering if you have any suggestion?

Comment: Remove default_value and try.

Comment: How do I run your code? I am getting TypeError: `dataset` must be a `tf.data.Dataset` object.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting default value= [-1]*4